# What are the rules to tell which Big-O it is from pseudo code?

Tags: big-o

I'm trying to figure out the rules to tell which Big-O it is from pseudo code. What are the rules?

So far I have found:

O(1) - if

O(n) - for if

O(n^2) - for for if

O(n^k)

O(log n)

O(n log n)

O(k^n)

Comment: It's not this simple. The loop conditions, amount the loop variable changes each iteration, `break`s and `continue`s, recursive calls, and many other factors make analysis more complicated than applying a couple rules of thumb.

Comment: A single loop could loop from 1 to n or from 1 to n^2, for example. You can't just count the number of `for`s.

Comment: There aren't any rules. The ones you listed are incorrect. Loops can run in constant time, or in log(n) time- just to give 2 quick examples.

Answer (score 0):

This website provides plenty of information on finding the time complexity of certain algorithms: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

It's best to look at and compare certain functions or data storage searches.

[image]